# What currency msg.value represents on different blockchains?

Tags: solidity, polygon, smart-contract

I'm writing a smart contract and testing on goerli and I want to deploy the smart contract to both mainnet and the polygon chain.

In a payable function, when I require `msg.value` to be greater than say 10000000000, does this mean on polygon chain the numerical value stays the same? so 10000000000 Wei in Ether becomes 10000000000 Wei in Matic, which considerably reduce the actual value?

See sample code:

```
        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
    }
```

here `uint256 cost=10000000000` In this example, should I manually covert `uint256 cost` to a much bigger number before deploying to polygon?  Is there a way to avoid the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes till i know one wei is one wei whatever EVM the contract is deployed.

Comment: Right, you are saying wei is a just unit and the value/price is separate. So i need to convert the numbers to keep the pricing more or less the same on the polygon chain.

Comment: Exactly. You can use Chainlink to get how much X wei of Matic is worth on USD.